# Is there an easier way to fix suffixes in names?

Tags: php, laravel

I am reading a text file that has some name inconsistencies. For example I have names like:

```
MILLER, WALTER MCNAB IV
DUPONT, THOMAS B. II
HARDEWAY, GRANT U. SR.
```

As you can see I can split the name by first name and last name however the suffixes are placed incorrectly. Ideally the names should be:

```
WALTER MCNAB MILLER IV
THOMAS B. DUPONT II
GRANT U. HARDEWAY SR.
```

That being said this is what I have but I feel Im over complicating something simple. Any tips?

```
private function extractFullName($name){


//I cant do V since V could be someone's middle initial also :(
        $suffix = collect(['II', 'III', 'IV', 'JR.', 'SR.']);

        // lets first assemble a full name from the row
        $fullNameArray = explode(",", $name);
        $firstName=trim($fullNameArray[1]);
        $lastName=trim($fullNameArray[0]);

        //lets look at the FIRST NAME for II/III/IV/JR./SR.

        $suffix = $suffix->each(function ($item, $key) use ($firstName, $lastName) {

            if (strpos($firstName, " ".$item)){
                $firstName = preg_replace('/'.$item.'$/', '', $firstName);
                $lastName.=' '.$item;
                return false;
            }

        });


        //Basically arranging it in a 'firstname lastname II/III/IV/JR./SR.' format
        $name = $firstName." ".$lastName);
        $name = ucwords(strtolower($lawyerName));
        return $name;
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as you're asking on how to improve it, not solve the problem.

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ < making assumptions about names is walking on shaky ground > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(musician)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you have at the minute shouldn't work as you're not passing the `$firstname` and `$lastname` by reference.

This being said you could simplify you code quite a bit:

```
private function extractFullName($name)
{
    $suffix = collect(['II', 'III', 'IV', 'JR.', 'SR.'])->first(function ($suffix) use ($name) {
        return ends_with($name, $suffix);
    });

    $name = $suffix ? rtrim($name, $suffix) : $name;

    return collect(explode(',', $name))->map(function ($name) {
        return trim(ucwords(strtolower($name)));
    })->reverse()->implode(' ') . ' ' . $suffix;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again Ross.

Answer (score 1):

Are the examples always like that:

`[surename], [name] [secondname]. [extra]` ??

Then you can do

```
$arr = explode(" ", $name); 
$a=array_pop($arr);
$b=trim(array_shift($arr),','); 
array_push($arr,$b); 
array_push($arr,$a); 
print implode(' ',$arr);
```

Read @CD001 comment :-)